# Étymologie de « un fou dans une poche »

Tags: expressions, étymologie, québec

Je serais la première à dire que le Québec regorge d'expressions colorées, toutes aussi farfelues les unes que les autres. Il est relativement facile pour moi de trouver et de comprendre l'origine de la majorité de ces expressions, qui sont très culturelles. Or, je me suis surprise aujourd'hui à lancer l'expression « un fou dans une poche », et je n'arrive pas à m'expliquer, même avec quelques recherches, d'où vient cette expression qui signifie que la personne n'est pas dupe et habituellement qu'elle a fait, ou fera, quelque chose qui est à son avantage.

Quelle est l'étymologie de cette expression?

Comment: Est-ce qu'on peut avoir un exemple d'utilisation ? J'ai du mal à interprêter la position d'« habituellement » dans la phrase.

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas Je dirais que c'est un peu interchangeable avec quelque chose du genre « tu me prends pour un idiot? ». Je pense à un exemple concret et je reviens...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Je crois que cette expression viens de [Les Fourberies de Scapin](http://fourberies.free.fr/texfou.htm), de Molière.  À la deuxième scène, on peut lire ceci :

> GÉRONTE: Ne saurais-tu trouver quelque moyen pour me tirer de peine?
>
> SCAPIN: J'en imagine bien un ; mais je courrais risque, moi, de me faire assommer.
>
> GÉRONTE: Eh ! Scapin, montre-toi serviteur zélé. Ne m'abandonne pas, je te prie.
>
> SCAPIN: Je le veux bien. J'ai une tendresse pour vous qui ne saurait souffrir que je vous laisse sans secours.
>
> GÉRONTE: Tu en seras récompensé, je t'assure ; et je te promets cet habit-ci, quand je l'aurai un peu usé.
>
> SCAPIN: Attendez. Voici une affaire que je me suis trouvée fort à propos pour vous sauver. Il faut que vous vous mettiez dans ce sac, et que...

À lire la scène en entier, on peut facilement y voir la source de cette expression.

Comment: Énorme ! Et bien vu ! L'expression restait incompréhensible sans cette référence. Elle semble confirmée par le titre de cet [article](http://www.erudit.org/culture/cd1035538/cd1043067/8425ac.pdf) !

Comment: Fantastique! Bravo mon cher, je vous tire mon chapeau!

Answer (score 3):

Dix ans après on le trouve au [*Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/un_fou_dans_une_poche) et [ailleurs](https://oreilletendue.com/2015/08/12/un-fou-sa-poche/) et on voit que c'était [documenté](https://books.google.fr/books?id=FTxcAAAAMAAJ&q=%22un%20fou%20dans%20une%20poche%22&dq=%22un%20fou%20dans%20une%20poche%22&hl=fr&ei=9jS5TKr5MIjKswa2nPzEDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result) en 1989, effectivement dans un cas pour dire qu'*on n'est pas dupe*, dans l'autre pour signifier *complètement fou* (Clas, Seutin). Et pour des attestations à l'écrit dans le premier cas ils donnent Jean Barbeau (1973) dans *Le chant du sink* (« Pis là, parce que j'suis à l'asile, tout est permis... Un fou d'une poche ... ») ; on note *d'une poche*, celui qui se trouve dedans ou en provient, *lié* par la poche pour ainsi dire.). Au début des années 2000 on le trouve dans des paroles de chansons de *La Chicane* (*La légende du laitier*, 2001) ainsi que dans le film *Séraphin : Un homme et son péché* (2002), basé sur l'oeuvre de Grignon (1933). Par exemple cet échange entre Donalda et Alexis dans le roman original :

[image]

<sup>*Séraphin: Nouvelles histoires des pays d'en haut*, Claude-Henri Grignon, Québéc Amérique, 1933, à la p. 235.</sup>

---

J'interprète le sens à partir du contexte de l'oeuvre de Grignon car au Québec je ne trouve pas de traces plus anciennes à l'écrit. Telle la différence de degré entre le *fou* et le *fou à lier*, il y a il me semble une différence entre celui-là et le fou qui est en plus dans une poche ; l'incapacité de se mouvoir, de voir et d'apprécier, en plus de l'incapacité tout court, comme on l'a un peu évoqué ailleurs. Et c'est non sans rappeller cette scène de Molière détaillée dans une autre réponse, mais je trouve difficile d'imaginer le personnage d'Alexis, une espèce de *don juan* exilé aux États-Unis de retour au pays, féru de l'auteur, lui qui révèle en plus, une journée où il préfère lire que bûcher sur sa terre à bois de chauffage, que c'est à l'école du soir avec Mlle Angélique qu'il a appris à lire et écrire, mais sait-on jamais ! Je vois *dans une poche* simplement comme un emploi adverbial, une surenchère de sens en contexte avec les objets usuels, comme la *poche* (*de patates* etc.). Et ensuite l'[antiphrase](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3225) donnant *pas complètement fou* dans le sens de *pas dupe*.

Comment: Étrangement, je ne connais pas l'expression.

Comment: J'avais retiré un exemple d'emploi dans le titre de l'article de André-G. Bourassa mais le texte est vraiment trop intéressant : [lien](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/cd/1993-n35-cd1043067/8425ac.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Dans le vieux patois Sartois les anciens, pour parler d'une personne au tempérament sanguin ou surexcitée utilisaient l'expression "celui la,ça doit être dur de le mettre dans une poche !". (Une poche étant un sac de jute destiné à contenir du blé ou de l'orge d'une dimension permettant d'y entrer un corps.) Le mot "poche" ramène à l'idée de"contention", répression des pulsions ".. Folie ?

Comment: Il y a une citation ?

Answer (score -3):

C'est vrai qu'on ne trouve pas grand-chose quant à l'origine de cette expression. Sur ce [forum](http://www.magarderie.com/forum/showthread.php?t=10421), il y a bien deux tentatives d'explication, mais peu convaincantes :

> Bien que le nom « poche » puisse être employé pour parler de l’entrejambe de ces messieurs, l’expression ci-dessus réfère plutôt à un sac. Un sac rempli de choses intéressantes. C’est donc une autre façon de désigner la loi du plus fort. Le plus fort gagnait le trésor.

…et…

> En réalité je crois que ça vient du Moyen Âge. Quand quelqu'un était fou, on le mettait dans une poche et on le jetait à la rivière pour qu'il meure…

Comment: Je ne pense pas que rapatrier des propos douteux sans justification, des ouï-dire ou des tergiversations en provenance d'autres forums apporte quoi que ce soit. Je ne cautionne pas et j'ai donc moinsé. Je me demande bien comment ceux qui ont plussé ont pu en retirer quelque chose.